# How to modify the option of ButtonStyle for one specific button?

Tags: xcode

Here is the thing.
I trying to use SwiftUI to make the ButtonStyle, to maintain the style sheet can be the same and simple to read. And they appear on every button which is great.
But there are a few specific buttons I need to use different background colors. (more than three)

I wonder is there a better method than adding the style sheet after every button that needs to change color?

here is my ButtonStyle:

```
struct StateButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        
        return configuration.label
            .frame(width: 183, height: 50)
            .background(Color("Orange"))
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ButtonStyle` is a normal struct. Just add a member `color` with a default value

```
struct StateButton: ButtonStyle {
    var color = Color("Orange")

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        
        return configuration.label
            .frame(width: 183, height: 50)
            .background(color)
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
    }
}
```

and use it either with the default background color

```
.buttonStyle(StateButton())
```

or with a different one

```
.buttonStyle(StateButton(color: .blue))
```

Comment: It's a very inspiring answer for a beginner. Thanks